# What is blockwise motion in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

The cursor-motion section of vim online help (:h) has a section called: `FORCING A MOTION TO BE LINEWISE, CHARACTERWISE OR BLOCKWISE`, but it doesn't define `BLOCKWISE` before that. `:h blockwise` takes you to blockwise visual(ctrl-v) section.

Does blockwise mean plain visual mode and block the text selected using visual mode?

Answer (score 6):

I could be wrong but from my understanding, the help is referring to `blockwise` and `blockwise visual` as one and the same.

`Linewise` (using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>):

[image: Linewise selection in Vim]

`Characterwise` (just using <kbd>v</kbd>):

[image: Characterwise selection in Vim]

and `Blockwise` (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>):

[image: Blockwise selection in Vim]

---

In terms of **forcing a motion** to be blockwise, consider a block selection with an insert at the beginning of the block:

Visual block insertion (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to select the block and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to insert at the beginning).

[image]

You can see the help for the visual block insertion by typing

```
:h v_b_i
```

Comment: This is brilliant!  Needs to be in the vim manual somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `vap`.

It visually selects a block, in this case a paragraph.

For more information look under `:help object-motions`

Also, http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/ seems useful.

Comment: thanks! so block referes to the visually selected text?

Comment: I'm not a vim guru, but I think block refers either to visual selection or to an motion pending operators.You can do `dap` which would delete a paragraph. I often use `ci)` that changes the content between parentheses.